# Check network connectivity when app is in Background(has been killed) Android nougat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-7.1-nougat

I am using a broadcast receiver in my project to detect network change. If network comes up then I am uploading some files to the server. But it is not working in android nougat. I am aware of the fact that declaring broadcast receiver in manifest file no longer works, you need to explicitly register it. But it has to be unregistered while activity is destroyed and broadcast receiver not longer can listen.But I want to use it in the background even when the app is not running. I do not know how to do that in android nougat. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you upload your file in service

Comment: Do I need to check network change in the service?

Comment: i think so but if you upload image or any task that need constrains like the network i think you should use a job i recommend `firebase JobDispatcher`

Comment: Hm, your broadcast receiver should contact a service which then uploads the stuff or did I understand your problem wrongfully?

Comment: That's what I am doing already, broadcast receiver contacts the service which then uploads the file, but in Android N, we have to register broadcast receiver in the activity and should kill the receiver when that activity is destroyed. I want to check whether the Internet is available or not in the background even when the app is not running. There is no problem in Android version M or below, In Android N broadcast receiver does not work like that. So I am finding a solution check network connectivity in the background